# example for a function convergent in measure and in $L_p$ but not almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

I was looking for an example of a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure and in $L_p$, but not almost everywhere. The book I'm studying (Real Analysis for Graduate students) is trying to give an example, but it seems so artificial to me, and honestly I don't get that. (it defines kind of an arclength measure) Can anyone give a relatively simple example, if possible? If someone can just give the example, then I believe I can prove it, so no need to write a detailed proof. However, I couldn't come up with such an example yet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\chi_{[0,1]}$, $\chi_{[0,1/2]}$, $\chi_{[1/2,1]}$, $\chi_{[0,1/4]}$, $\ldots$.

Comment: @DavidMitra : doesn't this converge a.e to 0?

Comment: @Tryss No. It converges pointwise nowhere. (the next three are $\chi_{[1/4,2/4]}$, $\chi_{[2/4,3/4]}$, ,$\chi_{[3/4,1]}$, Then you "slide an interval of length $1/8$  across $[0,1]$". Etc...)

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thanks a lot, it's a great example!

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I misuderstand your sequence of functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @David Mitra suggested, define $f_n:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ by $$f_n = \chi_{\left[j2^{-k}, (j+1)2^{-k}\right]}$$
for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $0\leqslant j<2^k$ and $n=2^k+j$. Then for each $n$, $f_n=1$ on a set of measure $2^{-k}$ (where $k=\lfloor \lg n\rfloor$) and is $0$ elsewhere. Given $\varepsilon>0$ (we can assume without loss of generality that $\varepsilon < 1$ and $\eta>0$, choose $N$ so that $2^{-\lfloor \lg N\rfloor}<\eta$, then for $n\geqslant N$, $$\mu(\{x:f_n(x)>\varepsilon\}<\eta, $$
so that $f_n\to0$ in measure.

For any $p\in[1,\infty)$ we have
$$\|f_n\|_p = \left(\int (\chi_{\left[j2^{-k},(j+1)2^{-k}\right]})^p\right)^{\frac1p} = \left((2^{-k})^{\frac1p}\right) = 2^{-\frac kp} \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$$
However, given $x\in[0,1]$, for each $k$ there exist $0\leqslant i,j< 2^k$ such that $x\in\left[i2^{-k},(i+1)2^{-k}\right]$ but $x\notin\left[j2^{-k},(j+1)2^{-k}\right]$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ doesn't exist, as $f_n(x)=0$ for infinitely many $n$ and $f_n(x)=1$ for infinitely many $n$.